# MySQL How to identify top 3 issues for a row/entry across columns where columns are numbers and columns are more than 3

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have the below data set example - I need to see for an entry, what is the 3 most affected issues by score across the columns (10 or more) - it's a large data set.

```
store|P|Q|L |J|K|D
DC12 |2|3|12|1|2|1
DC45 |3|1|3 |2|6|4
DC78 |5|5|4 |4|3|3
HF45 |1|2|4 |5|6|8
```

I have tried googling and looking at other questions posed but cannot seem to find the answer for my question.

I'm not sure if I'm framing it correctly but I would like to somehow identify each store's top 3 issues by value across the columns

i.e I expect store DC12 to come back as L,Q and P or K as the top 3 issues. 
DC45 to come back with K,D and L or P

Apologies if this is framed incorrectly or something super simple.

Comment: just post sample data with expected output.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @SalmanA It is Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17

Comment: Then you aren't using MySQL at all - you are using SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION ALL` inside a `CTE` to return all the numeric values as 1 column and another `CTE` to return the top 3 for each store with `ROW_NUMBER()`.
Finally group by store:

```
with 
  cte as (
    select store, p as col, 'P' name from tablename union all
    select store, q, 'Q' from tablename union all
    select store, l, 'L' from tablename union all
    select store, j, 'J' from tablename union all
    select store, k, 'K' from tablename union all
    select store, d, 'D' from tablename
  ),
  ctern as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by store order by col desc) rn
    from cte
  )
select store, string_agg(name, ',') within group (order by rn) [TOP ISSUES]
from ctern
where rn <= 3
group by store
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=682a88597859b7cfff88e9de5347f952).
Results:

```
STORE | TOP ISSUES
DC12  | L,Q,P     
DC45  | K,D,L     
DC78  | Q,P,J     
HF45  | D,K,J
```

Comment: Thanks @forpas - I get the below error Msg 10757, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
The function 'string_agg' may not have a WITHIN GROUP clause.

Comment: I can't tell what the error means. You can check the demo that it works. Try without: `within group (order by rn)`